# Login script doesn't work

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a login script, but it doesn't let me sign in even though the account information are correct. I've used this login script in the past, but it used MySQL, so I changed a couple of things so I would work with MySQLi, but it doesn't.

Config.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","wachtwoord","huizenverkoop");

// Database verbinding controleren
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Kan geen verbinding maken met MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Updated: login.php

```
include 'config.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['persoon'])!="")
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['loginnu']))
{
    $gebruikersnaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gebruikersnaam']);
    $wachtwoord = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['wachtwoord']);

    $gebruikersnaam = trim($gebruikersnaam);
    $wachtwoord = trim($wachtwoord);

    $query = "SELECT id, gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM persoon WHERE gebruikersnaam='$gebruikersnaam'";
    $row = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($row);

    if($count == 1 && $row['wachtwoord']==md5($wachtwoord)){
        $_SESSION['persoon'] = $row['id'];
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        header("Location: login.php?fout=true");
    }
}

if (@$_GET['fout'] == 'true'){
    $melding = "De ingevulde gegevens kloppen niet.";
    include('alert.php');
}
```

Gebruikersnaam means username and wachtwoord means password. When I press the button "log in" it sends me to login.php?fout=true. Fout means wrong.

```
<form method="post">
    <h1 class="box-titel">Inloggen</h1>
        <div class="controle">
            <input type="text"      class="speciaal-tekstveld" name="gebruikersnaam"    placeholder="Gebruikersnaam"    required>
            <input type="password"  class="speciaal-tekstveld"  name="wachtwoord"       placeholder="Wachtwoord"        required>
        </div>
            <input type="submit"    class="grootknop"           name="loginnu"          value="Inloggen">
</form>
```

Persoon table:

```
id  int(2)
gebruikersnaam  varchar(50)
wachtwoord  varchar(255)
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: You need to [fetch the data](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: 1)  in your form include action="" if you are redirecting to the same page.. Make it like <form method="post" action=""> . &&  2) $con is not defined as per your code. if it's included than update your with connection code.

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: @Qirel, I've already tried to fix my error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array on line 23: "if($count == 1 && $row['wachtwoord']==md5($wachtwoord)){", but I can't get it to work, where do I have to put the fetch_assoc()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to fetch the data, not just query it. You currently are trying to use a MySQLi object, which is the result from the query, this isn't an array with the data from the database, it needs to be fetched first. You'll need something like this

```
$query = "SELECT id, gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM persoon WHERE gebruikersnaam='$gebruikersnaam'";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // Fetch the data!
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1 && $row['wachtwoord']==md5($wachtwoord)){
     // ....
```

You can also check for the password in the query, reducing some of your code. Basically, if you can do something in SQL, do it in SQL.

---

In addition to this, you shouldn't use `md5` for storing passwords. PHP has a built-in [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function which is a lot more secure!

You should also take advantage of using *prepared statements*, to protect your database against SQL-injection attacks.

Reading-material & documentation

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Comment: It works! Thank you. I'll definitely try the password_hash() function. And I'll also read the documentation. Once again thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a trouble with mysqli connection.

The deal is in this row:

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($row);
if($count == 1 ...
```

You are expecting that will be at least one row in table. If you are shure, that such row is exist in database, I think that $count receiving false because of error.

Answer (score 0):

In your code your `$con` is not defined, I assume you defined it, so you need to test to make sure you have a connection.  Also you are not reporting any errors from your mysqli query.  You could try each of these to do those:

http://www.php.net/function.mysqli_connect

```
//check make sure you have it
if (!$con) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

And report errors from `mysqli_query`, and of course you need to fetch the row, as suggested by Qirel:

```
$query = "SELECT id, gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM persoon WHERE gebruikersnaam='$gebruikersnaam'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row = $result->fetch_row();
```

Comment: $con is defined in my config.php file. config.php is included above if(isset($_POST['loginnu']))

Comment: OK then you can just check to make sure you have it there, instead of defining it.

Answer (score 0):

There may be three problems in it.

1) In your form include action="" if you are redirecting to the same page.. Make it like,

```
 <form method="post" action="">
```

2)  $con is not defined as per your code. if it's included than update your code with config file.

3) Fetch row Like,

```
$res = $conn -> query("SELECT id, gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM persoon WHERE gebruikersnaam='$gebruikersnaam'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['wachtwoord'];
```

Also, Start some error log in your script.